# Access model object property in controller

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I have this function in my model :

```
User.createUser = async (userData, res) => {
  console.log("User model userData", userData);

  // Before creation, we check if the email already exists into the database
  const email = userData.email;
  console.log("User model email", email);
  const findUser = await User.findOne({ where: { email } }).catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
  });

  // If the email doesn' t exists, we create the user
  if (!findUser) {
    User.create(userData)

      .then((user) => {
        console.log("User model user" + user);
        res.json({ message: "Votre compte a été créé" });
      })

      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  }
};
```

In my controller I have this code :

```
 const newUser = await User.createUser(userData, res);
```

What I need is to get all datas from the user I've just created into the newUser variable, because I need its id to make other stuff just after creation.

Comment: What exactly do you lack in `newUser`? Sequelize will return a model instance with all simple fields (w/o associated model props). If you need  plain object from a model instance then just call `const plainUser = newUser.get({ plain: true })`

Comment: `createUser` function is not returning any value and closing the request with `res.json` within the function. If you would like to do additional operations, you can  
 remove `res.json` from the `createUser` and do `return await User.create`. Then, `newUser` should have the Sequelize model.  Also, you are missing `else` for `if(!findUser)`